# Which menu group identifier does the copy relative path belong

Tags: vscode-extensions

[image: screenshot]

I want to add a menu item here.

but I only saw these menu group identifiers on the official documents.

[image: screenshot]

[Document Link](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_new-menu-group-identifiers)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Use example：

```
{ 
  "command": "extension.command",
  "group": "6_copypath@5"
}
```